# Is it correct to say "your hand got stuck in the helmet" or "your hand got stuck under the strap" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

[image]

I help my daughter to put on her helmet, but we got a situation like the above picture. Her hand rested on the strap like that.

I said sorry to her.

Is it correct to say "**I am sorry, I got your hand stuck in the helmet**" or "**your hand got stuck in the helmet**" ? But her hand is not "**in the helmet**".

Is it correct to say "**I am sorry, I got your hand stuck under the strap**" or "**your hand got stuck under the strap**"? But her hand is not "**under the strap**".

Comment: "Your hand got caught in the strap." The strap is round her wrist.

Comment: Yes, **caught**. Her hand isn't 'stuck', because she can remove it.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters.  Technically, the *helmet* really just refers to the part shaped like a bowl, so if I heard "her hand got stuck in the helmet" that picture is not what I would imagine.

Comment: She may have put her hand under the strap but it is hard to imagine that her hand in that position resulted from some action of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll make this into an answer.

The hand isn't inside the helmet - it's just the strap that is round her wrist. Most people would say "Your hand got caught in the strap".

Comment: I'll bet you he won't select your answer or anyone's answer. Have you seen all the questions he hasn't closed?